# Basic question about socket programming using Boost ASIO

Tags: sockets, boost-asio

I am relatively new to socket programming. I am currently trying examples provided with boost::asio. I have a general question about sockets.

Lets say I am connecting a remote endpoint using tcp::socket.connect(endpoint,error) function. Can I both send and receive using the same socket object or do I have to create another socket object to send the data?

Thanks,
Devendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can both send and recv on the same socket. E.g a typical use of a *client* socket would be to connect, send some data, read some data, etc depending on the protocol.

A useful link to learn about boost asio would be a free eBook by Boris Schäling: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/index.html